# Quickblox QBChatservice login logs jabber ID but callback and getPrivateChatManager aren't working

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

Whenever I use the following to login to QBChatService:

```
chatService.login(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // success
            Log.d("CHAT_READY", String.valueOf(chatService.isLoggedIn()));
            try {
                chatService.startAutoSendPresence(60);
            } catch (SmackException.NotLoggedInException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List errors) {
            // errror
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
            dialog.setMessage("chat login error: " + errors).create().show();
        }
}
```

I observe the following log output:

```
D/QBASDK﹕ Connecting to chat..
D/QBASDK﹕ Connected. Login to chat, currentUser JID: myUserID-myAppID, resource: someRandomString
```

Which I assumed was an indication that login was successful. However, the onSuccess and onError functions of the callback are not called.

Also, Calling

```
QBChatService.getInstance().getGroupChatManager()
```

returns null.

Am I missing something on setting up chat service properly?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I did was allow QBChatService to print debug logs. Doing that revealed that a password not verified error was being returned by the service.

Next, I tried using the BaseService token as password but same result. It seems you can't just use user.SetID, do QBAuth.login(user...) and then set Password in the onSuccess when using facebook login.

In the end, I had to store the facebook access token, login again with facebook (sign in using social provider) before setting the password with the BaseService token to login to the chat service successfully.